# Android app building using ant - what about android_rules.xml?

Tags: android, ant

I just got my build working using ant after a lot of effort.

Basically it's pretty simple now though:

```
<project name="MyDroid" default="help" >
    <property file="local.properties" />
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property file="default.properties" />

    <path id="android.antlibs">
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/anttasks.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/sdklib.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/androidprefs.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/apkbuilder.jar" />
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/jarutils.jar" />
    </path>

    <taskdef name="setup"
            classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask"
            classpathref="android.antlibs" 
      />
    <import file="C:\Applications\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml" />

    <setup import="false" />

    <!-- comment this line for build using nant, its silly , i know -->
    <!--<import file="${sdk.dir}/platforms/android-7/templates/android_rules.xml"  />-->

</project>
```

As you can see i'm referencing the ant's main_rules.xml instead of that of the platform i'm using.

In my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Am I safe using the ant main_rules instead of the platform ones?
2. I noticed that not all platforms have a main_rules.xml? Starting android-9 the file is no longer in the templates directory?
3. When I tried referencing the main_rules from the android-7 directory, I got many errors using my nant buildscript. Mostly attributes that could not be found in libraries i'm referencing. Should I be using the main_rules.xml from the minSdk version or the targetSdk version?
4. I couldn't use ${target} because it is set to target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7 and that just didn't work because that's no real path on disk. Any solution for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some time prior to android-16, the android command-line tool was added and generates a build.xml file which includes the `${android-sdk}/tools/ant/main_rules.xml` file.